# OpenCart - Sending the price from item page while adding item to basket

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

Please, help me in my problem.

The goal is to show several prices on product page which depend on quantity.
So I created several options which display the quantity with prices.
Using jQuery I change frontend price on product page.

So now the question is.
By default when I add an item to basket the system adds it with its price in admin panel.
But how can I send that price which was chosen by user in radiobutton (an option) ?

Trying get the decisin I found out that "button-cart" element calls add() function in checkout/cart.php but where can I catch price in this current order?

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily done using `Discounts` in administration. Go to Your administration, hit Catalog -> Products, pick one You want to have different prices regarding the amount put into the cart, click Edit and navigate yourself to the `Discounts` tab - here add one row per amount-price combination.

E.g. let's say a product price is $100 but You want to sell one item for $98 only if user orders 10 pcs, for $96 only if user orders 20 pcs, for $94 only if he orders 30 pcs etc. In this table You'll add three new rows and add 10, 20, 30 as amounts and 98, 96 and 94 as product price for each said amount.

After saving when using default (and from default derived) theme on the product's detail page You should see a table depicting the price change upon the amount ordered and after ordering such amount the price in the cart will be automatically adjusted by OpenCart itself.

No programmatic changes are needed at all.